# werid behavior of sudo

Tags: linux, echo, sudo

In my linux machine, path are configured as follows

> **non-root user**:
> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/java
>
> **root user**:
> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

when i tried to

> sudo echo $PATH

it shows non-root user path only not root path

but when i put

> echo $PATH

in script and tried to execute with sudo, it gives root path. Do anyone knows this reason? Actually sudo is for executing command as root but in my first case it is not working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `sudo echo $PATH`, the shell expands `$PATH` before ever calling `sudo`, so you are really running this:

```
sudo echo /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/java
```

which gives the results you are seeing - the non-root user `PATH` being displayed.

When `echo $PATH` is embedded in a script and you do `sudo somescript.sh`, the shell that is running the script runs as root, and so when it expands `$PATH` as part of interpreting the script, it sees root's environment and displays the root version of the PATH.

In order to avoid the early expansion in the first case, you could do this:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'
```

assuming your `sudoers` is set up to allow that. The single quotes prevent the non-root users shell from expanding the variable before passing it as a command to `bash`.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo echo $PATH` executes `echo $PATH` as root in the current non-root environment, i.e. with the non-root value of `$PATH`. When you do `sudo bash somescript.sh`, bash is executed as root and during its initialization, it loads the root environment containing root's value of `$PATH`.